# ASP.NET GridView Image Command Button Problem (Multiple PostBacks)

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET GridView Image Command Button causes Multiple PostBacks.Is this is a known issue ?  or is there any solution(not workaround).

Comment: Are you sure? I never saw this issue

Comment: Thank you for your response.Yes..This is the code i have used "<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="" ShowEditButton="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="70px" /> </asp:CommandField>When i click on image button it will cause double post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this way

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Button" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/Editicon.png" OnClick="Button_Click" /> 
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{}

I m sure you wont face ne problem with this

Comment: Thank you for your replay....ok i accept this.....but i want to know whether this is a known bug?.......

Comment: I have never faced this problem, If I get a chance I will like to test ur code so that I can try figure out

Comment: k..But with your it is possible.I am telling about my code.When i convert button type to "button" or "link",it is work fine.Problem only with Button type "image" option

Comment: I have used using images as well but I never faced this problem

Comment: please check this link "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GVImageCommandButtonProb.aspx".

Comment: It is giving me page not found